# How do I change the date on a time object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have

```
> time = Time.zone.now
=> Tue, 03 Apr 2018 09:44:14 EDT -04:00
```

I want something like

```
> time.set_date_to(Date.parse("2018-04-13"))
> time
=> Tue, 13 Apr 2018 09:44:14 EDT -04:00
```

Does this exist?

Comment: FYI: you can use `Time.current` instead of `Time.zone.now`

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
time = Time.zone.now.change(year: 2018, month: 4, day: 13)
```

Here is the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change)

Answer (score 0):

Jumping off of [MrShemek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2039726/mrshemek)'s answer I monkeypatched `Time`:

```
class Time
  def set_date_to(date_or_date_string)
    date = date_or_date_string.is_a?(Date) ? date_or_date_string : Date.parse(date_or_date_string)
    change(year: date.year, month: date.month, day: date.day)
  end
end
```

Which seems to work

Answer (score 0):

If you're not working with a Rails project (or does not wish to load `active_support`), you can use Ruby's `Date` library.

With it you can perform basic time math, like so:

```
require 'date'

d = Time.now.utc.to_datetime # Datetime preserves time and date information
d.next_day(10)               # same as d + 10
d.prev_day                   # same as d - 1
d.prev_month(2)              # same as d << 2
d.next_month                 # same as d >> 1
d.to_time                    # You can convert back to a Time object if needed.
```

`DateTime` can deal with leap seconds/years but not with timezones.